# Entity Framework converting the query to is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I run `= null` in Management Studio, it returns no rows but when I run `is null` I get data back. In Entity Framework, it is converting the query to is null, Is there any alternative so I can just do the `= null` in Entity Framework?

This return no rows

```
SELECT *
FROM cart c
WHERE OrderId = NULL
```

This return 1000 rows

```
SELECT *
FROM cart c
WHERE OrderId IS NULL
```

EF List count 1000 rows

```
var Pending = (from c in db.Cart 
               where sc.OrderId == null
               select sc.CartId).ToList();
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for details on Ansi Null settings in SQL

Comment: Use DBNull.Value

Comment: can i convert int? to DBNull?

Comment: Your SQL does not make sense

Comment: Not sure what you mean what does not make sense?

Comment: I meant that, since `NULL = NULL` is always false in SQL, I don't understand why you would write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null means unknown value. In SQL trying to equate any value to NULL will result in FALSE, which makes sense. As such, 2 = NULL is FALSE. NULL = NULL is FALSE. However, column IS NULL checks that the value of the column is NULL.

The semantics of C# is different and eventually translates your query to IS NULL when the EF framework sends the query to the server.

Comment: is there a way to send the query to the server using `= NULL`?  the id is a `int?`

Comment: Well, what's the point? The result is FALSE in advance. You will get no row. Maybe you could explain what you are trying bro achieve.